# mysql match letter/number field with letter field without duplicates

Tags: mysql, regex, concatenation

i have fields in two mysql tables i need to match... in the product table i have mixed letter/number keys (product_code) such as MM123 and then in a collection table i have just the letters as a key (collection_code) such as MM...

i tried this:

```
select p.*
from product p, collection c
where p.product_code LIKE CONCAT(c.collection_code ,'%')
```

however i'm getting multiple entries matched because collection_code has entries such both M and MM so it returns for both product_code = M123 and product_code =  MM123

i think what i want is something like this:

```
select p.*
from product p, collection c
where p.product_code LIKE CONCAT(c.collection_code ,REGEXP  '[^0-9 \.]+')
```

but i cant seem to get it exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
JOIN collection c
ON p.product_code REGEXP CONCAT('^', c.collection_code, '[0-9]+$')
```